# post photo to facebook using windows phone app

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I am trying to post a photo to facebook wall, for which I am using Facebook c# sdk. I have used the following code :

```
    var fb = new FacebookClient(App.AccessToken);
            var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>
   {
        { "message", "Olav is testing Facebook C# SDK" },
        { "picture", "http://download.codeplex.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=facebooksdk&DownloadId=170794&Build=17672" },
        { "name", "Facebook C# SDK" },
        { "caption", "http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/" },
        { "description", "The Facebook C# SDK helps .Net developers build web, desktop, Silverlight, and Windows Phone 7 applications that integrate with Facebook." },
        { "privacy", new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                { "value",  "SELF" }
            }
        }
    };

            fb.PostAsync("me/feed", parameters);
```

It is working fine for the given picture url. But what if i want the picture to be the one created by the user using the phone app. If I give any value to picture field other than a url, then it gives an error. Can someone please tell how to do this, or is there any other method to post an image from app to facebook wall?

Comment: Please, somebody answer...

Answer (score 1):

That's not how you share a local photo. What you're doing currently is sharing a link with custom picture,caption,description etc.

To share a photo with [c# sdk](http://www.thepcwizard.in/2013/02/working-with-facebook-c--sharp-sdk.html) try this:

```
    var fb = new FacebookClient(App.AccessToken);       

    var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    parameters["name"] = "Description for the pic";
    parameters["TestPic"] = new FacebookMediaObject
    {
        ContentType = "image/jpeg",
        FileName = "photo_name.jpg"

    }.SetValue(File.ReadAllBytes(Server.MapPath("~\\Images\\photo_name.jpg")));

    dynamic res = fb.Post("me/Photos", parameters);

    // res.id contains the returned photo id
```

Replace the `Server.MapPath` with your photo URI.
Parameter `TestPic` could be anything you like. It is used as the name in the multipart/form-data when you upload the file.

You can follow this [detailed tutorial](http://www.thepcwizard.in/2013/07/sample-app-using-facebook-c-sharp-sdk.html), if still any problem.